# How to install local applications in ltsp thin clients?

Tags: chromium, emacs, ltsp

I've configured a ltsp server at home and built the thin client. Though, I'd now like to know how to add local applications to the thin client, namely `chromium-browser` and `emacs24`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to **chroot** into your thin client environment and install the app, then **update** your client image. Add an entry to your **lts.conf** and finally give the command to run the application as a local app from the thin client.

Detailed information on how to perform this can be found here:
[How to run applications as local app](http://wiki.ltsp.org/wiki/Ltsp-localapps)